# Binding ContextMenu inside Button that is inside a ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an ItemsControl inside a UserControl, and my ItemsControl ItemTemplate consist of a button. I can get the button's binding command to work, but cannot get the ContextMenu inside the button to work. Can someone show me how my Binding should look inside my button's ContextMenu?

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding People}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel Margin="0" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ShowPeopleDetailsAction, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}" 
                    CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameterIndex}" Background="Black" Cursor="Hand" Margin="1,0,14,10">
                <Button.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Clear" Command="{Binding DataContext.ClearPeopleDetailsAction, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}" 
                                  CommandParameter="{Binding CommandParameterIndex}" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Button.ContextMenu>
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="/Resources;component/Images/people.png" Width="112"/>
                            <Label Content="{Binding PowerSupplyName, FallbackValue=default}" 
                                   Visibility="{Binding IsConfigured, Converter={StaticResource booleanToStringConverter}, FallbackValue=Visible}" 
                                   Foreground="White" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="0,15,0,0" Padding="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="110" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Could you describe *what* isn't working?

Comment: The binding on the contextmenu does not work. If I right click and select clear, nothing happens.

Comment: Are you seeing binding errors in the output window? Is that command actually being assigned to?

Comment: @BradleyDotNET, there are no binding errors. When I start up my application, I do not see the binding being set. stukselbax, I will check out that link you posted to see if it will help. Thanks.

Comment: If there are no binding errors, then your binding likely isn't the problem. Make sure that you are initializing the bound property correctly.

Comment: @stukselbax, the link you posted was close enough to my problem that it fixed it...thanks.